# Can PHP file_exists check remapped subdirectory?

Tags: php

I have two websites using different languages but the same images. I remapped one website's image subdirectory to the image directory of the other, because the directory's images are constantly changing and being updated.

I have a function that needs to check if the file exists in the subdirectory, but doesn't seem to work on the website using the remapped subdirectory.

I just want to verify, can PHP's file_exists function check a remapped, but otherwise empty subdirectory?

Comment: Do you mean you are using `file_exists()` on another server? If so, I don't think it would work, try with `file_get_contents()` or something instead, or a custom function maybe

Comment: No, both websites are on the same server. The image directory for one website is remapped to the image directory of the other website on the same server.